# Delete command not work after create trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I create a simple function and trigger to delete all rows from tb_users when a row from tb_city is deleted:

```
create or replace function delete_user()
returns trigger as
$$
begin
    delete from rl_user_city where user_id in (select distinct user_id from rl_user_city where city_id = old.id) and city_id = old.id;
    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

drop trigger if exists t_delete_user on tb_city;

create trigger t_delete_user
before delete on tb_city
for each row
execute procedure delete_user();
```

After I create this trigger, the command `delete` is not working: `delete from tb_city where id = 385;`

My tables:

tb_city:

```
id: int
city: string
```

tb_user_city:

```
user_id: int
city_id: int
```

I run, but the row is not deleted...

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use a foreign key for this? You're now trying to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 2):

In a before delete trigger the value `NEW` is null. A null return value will block the deletion from happening. You need to `RETURN OLD` from a delete trigger instead.

If I am not mistaken, if you simply want to delete all users that are registered in a city you are deleting the `DELETE` command in the trigger function can be much simpler:

```
DELETE FROM rl_user_city WHERE city_id = OLD.id
```